# Blender Armature not looping continuously

Tags: armature, looping

I don't understand why this test animation doesn't cycle continuously.. Must have missed something simple but can't find it :-( I tried everything, different tutorials etc. but I can't get it to work.

https://pasteall.org/media/c/5/c5145484239e484b000bb1c48612d0bb.blend

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have created a rotation on W, X, Y and Z, but for the moment you have only created a cycle on W, so you also need to create a *Cycles* modifier for X, Y and Z: Select all the tracks and *Shift E* > *Make Cyclic*).

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much !! <3